# How to read the filename from an XML file

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to read the filename of an image from the XML file I run the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r'...\57128.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
a = root.find('.//filename')
print(a)
```

But instead of 57128.png I get this output: `<Element 'filename' at 0x000001ED3297C4A8>`
This is what the xml file contains:

```
<annotation>
  <folder>save</folder>
  <filename>57128.png</filename>
  <size>
    <width>1280</width>
    <height>720</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
  </size>
```

What else can I do to get the filename as it is written in the XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved I used

```
a = root.find('.//filename').text
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Use `findtext`:

```
filename = root.findtext('filename')
```